# Loop Values from client entered textfield?

Tags: javascript

iv been trying to get the textfield values entered by a client to be used in a loop as the start and end point both are to be entered and then calculated, i have the loop working perfectly when the variables r set values but cant retrieve them from the textfields and use them  (il also simplify what it needs to do each loop) and then put the answer in the 3rd textfield? below il post a small snippet of where the issue is any help would be awesome.

```
<SCRIPT language = JavaScript>

function calculate() {
A = document.frmOne.txtStartNumber.value;
B = document.frmOne.txtEndNumber.value;
A = Number(A);
B = Number(B);
{
C = 0;
    for (i = A; i <= B; i++) {
       C = C + i*i*100
    };
}
D = C;

document.frmOne.txtAnswerNumber.value = D;
}

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: The `{` above the C and `}` above the D shouldn't be there.

Comment: I removed them but it still wont give me the answer in the ''txtAnswerNumber'' textfield box? do u have any other thoughts as to why it wont be posting the answer in there?

Comment: Wait, is this a Parody?

Comment: im new here i dont think u will be thinking of me if u know someone by this name?

Comment: no i didnt i just edited my name from my facebook name that i signed up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You don't need to encapsulate code inside a function randomly with `{ }`.

```
<form name="frmOne">
    <input type="text" name="txtStartNumber">
    <input type="text" name="txtEndNumber">
    <input type="text" name="txtAnswerNumber">

    <a href="javascript:calculate();">click me</a>
</form>

<script>
function calculate() {
    A = document.frmOne.txtStartNumber.value;
    B = document.frmOne.txtEndNumber.value;
    A = Number(A);
    B = Number(B);

    C = 0;
    for (i = A; i <= B; i++) {
        C = C + i * i * 100;
    }

    // this is not needed: D = C;

    document.frmOne.txtAnswerNumber.value = C;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Also take note of the semi-colon on the `for`'s closing instead of on the line inside of it.

Comment: I wanted to basically post the same answer. I just want to emphasize how this answer corrected your **very bad HTML**. 

``<SCRIPT language = javascript>`` 
is wrong to me on so many levels.

I prefer: ``<script type="text/javascript>"``

Answer (score 2):

The method below preserves the functionality of a form (e.g. submitting with enter) without using another page:

```
<form action="javascript:void(calculate())" name="frmOne">
    <input type="text" name="txtStartNumber">
    <input type="text" name="txtEndNumber"> 
    <input type="text" name="txtAnswerNumber">
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate() {
A = Number(document.frmOne.txtStartNumber.value);
B = Number(document.frmOne.txtEndNumber.value);
C = 0;
    for (i = A; i <= B; i++) {
       C += i*i*100;
    }

document.frmOne.txtAnswerNumber.value = C;
}
</script>
```